# O que significa "please tell me who you are" no git?

Tags: git, commit

Sou totalmente novo nessa área de tecnologia, estou acompanhando um curso mas travei. Quando tento dar um `git commit -m "commit inicial"` a mensagem em sequência no git é essa:

```
Author identity unknown

*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.

fatal: unable to auto-detect email address (got 'Kleber@Kleber-PC.(none)')
```

A partir daqui não sei o que fazer e como arrumar para que isso não apareça novamente, poderiam me ajudar por favor?

Answer (score 3):

Isso quer dizer que o Git não sabe quem você é. Pra funcionar ele precisa de um Email e de um nome para poder te identificar.

### Mas por quê?

O Git usa seu endereço de e-mail para associar seu nome a qualquer commit de sua autoria. Depois de enviar seus commits para um repositório público no GitHub, por exemplo, os metadados de autoria também são publicados. Isso que dizer que, quem for acessar o seu repositório, vai conseguir ver que foi você que fez X alterações no código e não outra pessoa.

#### Como resolver?

Vamos supor que seu Email é `kleber@gmail.com`.
Você vai precisar digitar estes dois comandos que são necessários pra te identificar, fique tranquilo que esse passo você só vai precisar fazer uma única vez:

```
git config --global user.email "kleber@gmail.com"
git config --global user.name "Kleber"
```

Feito isso o erro vai ser solucionado.